# How can I use ResourcesProvider/ResourcesLoader classes to load resources dynamically?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-11, resourcesloader, resourcesprovider

### Background

I've found these new classes of Android 11 ([ResourcesLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/loader/ResourcesLoader) and [**ResourcesProvider**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/loader/ResourcesProvider)) and I think they can let you provide your own resource loading for the entire app, which can help you to prefer strings from the cloud (like on Lokalise and Crowdin) , load themes, etc...

### The problem

I can't find any example of how to use them, and if I'm indeed correct on what I've found.

The only thing I've found about it is from this [cached article](https://jitinsharma.com/posts/taming-android-resources-and-layoutinflater-for-string-manipulation/?q=cache:NtfvHgBjYAgJ:https://jitinsharma.com/posts/taming-android-resources-and-layoutinflater-for-string-manipulation/%20&cd=19&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=il) of "Taming Android Resources and LayoutInflater for string manipulation":

> Android 11 has introduced ability to load resources dynamically via
> ResourcesLoader and ResourcesProvider. This is not just restricted to
> string files but also allows dynamic loading of drawables and other
> resource files. This is an approximate way of using these classes

```
val provider = ResourcesProvider.loadFromDirectory("/somepath/", null) // or loadFromApk() 
val loader = ResourcesLoader() loader.addProvider(provider) resources.addLoaders(loader) // Application resources
```

> There aren’t proper samples of this API provided
> right now and it’s only available on Android 11 and above, so there is
> a long time for this API to be usable for majority of apps.

### What I've found

I wanted to try it for the Lokalise library, which offers an instance of Resources (wrote about this [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69242170/878126)).

Sadly, I'm stuck right in the beginning, of finding how to use it to provide it with this instance.

It seems it's such a rare use case and new classes that almost nobody bothered writing about it. Even about the article I've found from 2020, it was removed and I had to use a cached version of it...

### The questions

1. Is it true that these classes can used for this purpose, of offering resources (strings/themes) dynamically?
2. Can it be used with Lokalise, so that I give it the instance of its SDK ?
3. Is there a support library for these classes, so that it could be used before Android API 30 ?

---

EDIT: found a sample [**here**](https://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2021/09/11/dynamic-resources.html). There, they use an APK file that is loaded, to use its resources as top priority:

```
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        
        val file = File(cacheDir, "overrideResources")
        unzip(ZipInputStream(assets.open("override.apk")), file)
  
        val rl = ResourcesLoader()
        rl.addProvider(ResourcesProvider.loadFromDirectory(file.path, null))
        resources.addLoaders(rl)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use ResourcesLoader/ResourceProvide?

---

1. Create compiled resources.
   For this, you can use aapt or aapt2, for example.

**Example with aapt:**

```
./aapt package -f -M AndroidManifest.xml -S ./res -I android.jar -F unsigned.apk
```

(./res folder must be have structure hierarchy , like ./res/drawable, ./res/layout , etc. with resources)

**Example with aapt2:**

```
./aapt2 compile "drawable\your_res_name.xml" -o "drawable"
./aapt2 link -o unsigned.apk -I "android.jar" -R "drawable\your_res_name_drawable.xml.flat" --manifest AndroidManifest.xml -v
```

AndroidManifest.xml should have the same package name for correct work with your main app.
android.jar , aapt , aapt2 files you can find in your sdk folder.
About all of flags you can read -> aapt -h , aapt2 -h

**AndroidStudio IDE**

Example - steps for building apk:

1. Create an empty project;
2. Add to AndroidManifest.xml the correct package name

```
<manifest package="your package">
```

Remove unnecessary tags

```
<application android:label, android:icon, etc...>
```

;

3. Add your resources to the project ./res folder;
4. Remove all unnecessary resources;
5. Remove from build.gradle file all dependecies.

```
plugins {
... //your settings
}
android {
...//your settings
}
dependencies {
}
```

6. Build -> Build APK.

---

2. After that, you got compiled resources, then:
   (or How to use compiled resources in your app dynamically)

```
File f = new File("unsigned.apk");

ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, MODE_READ_ONLY);

ResourcesProvider rp = ResourcesProvider.loadFromApk(pfd);

ResourcesLoader rl = new ResourcesLoader();
rl.addProvider(rp);

getResouces().addLoaders(rl);
```

That's all! Your resources in your app. You downloaded resources dynamically.

For reading resource, you can use:

```
getResouces().getIdentifier("your_res_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

---

Is there a support library for these classes, so that it could be used before Android API 30 ?

ResourcesLoader can not be used in previous API.

Comment: Can't the IDE do this instead?

Comment: Can do.  aapt, aapt2 is just an example.

Comment: Can you please explain the alternative in steps, of doing it all via the IDE, just like you did for aapt2 commands?

Comment: Create empty project with resources -> Config your AndroidManifest.xml -> Set gradlew steps -> Build apk

Comment: aapt2 looks easier - read about it - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2

Comment: Please explain it in the answer. In comments it seems very short and unclear. What is there to config and set?

Comment: Updated. Steps for building your .apk using IDE.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Hope I will have the time to check it out