# Android Load strings from remote file

Tags: android, string

In my app, I've only English strings and I want to be able to update the strings without releasing a new version.
I know there's a library called restring, but I prefer not using a library (and I saw it wasn't updated for more then a year now).

I read it's possible doing it with `ResourcesLoader` but I can't find any examples how to use it.

I will be happy to get an example how can I use that to load strings from a file instead of strings.xml

Thanks!

Comment: ResourcesLoader is not avaiable before SDK 30.....
However you have to implement something BEFORE build the final APK/AAB or it's not possibile to change strings in runtime or add translations without recompiling.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243609/how-can-i-use-resourcesprovider-resourcesloader-classes-to-load-resources-dynami

Comment: in theory, it would be possible to achieve this with some sort of api that gives you a key value pair to use, but what happens when loading of it fails is probably something to consider

Comment: it's possible to have something, same as Lokalise do for example.
it's not replacing the strings.xml but replacing the resource we use to fetch the strings.
for cases a string resource doesn't exist, we need to have a fallback (like use the string from the apk)

Comment: If you need this, you're going to have to ditch the Android built in resources functionality and use your own string localization API.  Android does not support loading resources at runtime from a remote (or local) file.  In fact the resources in the apk aren't the same files as you have on your disk, they get compiled as part of the build process.